# Copy one file to multiple folder with variable path

Tags: windows, cmd

I have *.txt in files in current directory and I like to copy it to multiple folder as listed below. How do I put any loop logic and copy to destination path ?

```
Source File: *.txt from current folder
```

Target Folder:

```
Path1="MyPath1"
Path2="MyPath2"
Path3="MyPath3"
Path4="MyPath4"
Path5="MyPath5"
Path6="MyPath6"
Path7="MyPath7"
Path8="MyPath8"
Path9="MyPath9"
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: PC Windows 10 and Windows Server 2020

Comment: You have used the [[tag:cmd]] tag, which suggests that you're typing this directly into a `cmd.exe` window session. Is that the case? or are you running this as a `cmd.exe` script, i.e. a [[tag:batch-file]]?

Answer (score 1):

To do this directly in a `cmd.exe` window, change the current directory to that of the one holding your `.txt` files, and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> something like this:

```batch-file
If Exist "*.txt" For %G In ("Location 1" "Location 2" "Location 3" "Location 4" "Location 5" "Location 6" "Location 7" "Location 8" "Location 9") Do If Exist "%~G\" Copy /Y "*.txt" "%~G"
```

---

To do this using a batch file, e.g. `Copy2All.cmd`:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

If Not Exist "*.txt" GoTo :EOF

For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('2^> NUL Set Locn[') Do Set "%%G="

Set "Locn[1]=Location 1"
Set "Locn[2]=Location 2"
Set "Locn[3]=Location 3"
Set "Locn[4]=Location 4"
Set "Locn[5]=Location 5"
Set "Locn[6]=Location 6"
Set "Locn[7]=Location 7"
Set "Locn[8]=Location 8"
Set "Locn[9]=Location 9"

For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %%G In ('2^> NUL Set Locn[') Do If Exist "%%~H\" Copy /Y "*.txt" "%%~H"
```

Please note that your question says from current folder, so I have not specified one. However, you should be aware that the 'current directory' is not necessarily the one in which the running batch file resides. If you want to ensure that, please replace both instances of `"*.txt"`, with `"%~dp0*.txt"`